# Implications of Babai's Proof that Graph Isomorphism is Quasi Polynomial Time

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, graph-isomorphism

In the context of the very recent talk by Lazlo Babai outlining that Graph Isomorphism (GI) is Quasi Polynomial Time, what are the broader implications of this result?  (I'm assuming the claim will stand peer review)

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/quasipoly.html

https://twitter.com/gabegaster

Apart from the inherent satisfaction of having solved a difficult open problem, what are the broader implications for Theoretical Computer Science from this result, if any? Specifically, should it impact our beliefs / strategy about P?=NP?

PS. Too bad GI was not NP-complete eh?

Comment: Is this too broad? Community votes please.

Comment: Ad PS: [check your understanding](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/845#845). That has not been proven yet, otherwise Babai's result would be very uninteresting.

Comment: @Raphael I think the breadth is OK. I've deleted the part of the question asking about specifics of the algorithm's performance, since the algorithm hasn't yet (to the best of my knowledge) been made public so that part isn't answerable. When the algorithm is made public, questions about its performance should be a separate question, I think.

Comment: The same question has been [posted a while ago on cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19962/consequences-of-a-quasi-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-the-graph-isomorphism-prob).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Some details about specifics are here https://twitter.com/gabegaster But yes, I'm waiting for a paper too. Not sure how much detail was revealed at the actual talk.

Comment: [Babai retracted the claim of quasipolynomial runtime](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html). Apparently there was an error in the analysis.